# FullCalendar: how to fetch new events by AJAX in the moment of month changing?

Tags: ajax, json, fullcalendar

I am learning FullCalendar JS plugin by Adam Shaw now. And first at all I want to say *"Thanks a lot"* to the plugin author.

What is a Calendar view? This is **a list of records** (calendar events). And I have to control this list size, or  I hit limits (no more than 1000  records can be passed from Controller to View).

I see two ways:

(1) Traditional Selectors above calendar  ('Please select month' - and I retrieve from Database only that month records (calendar events). Good - but  if  to start switching months inside Calendar - the other months will be empty (have no events)...

(2) To make 'pagination' of calendar events  from month to month:

2-1. If you switch months by "<>" buttons (inside Calendar section) - a page makes postback (rerender full page or rerender only calendar section by AJAX) and retrieves records of picked month.

2-2. Probably the best way: If you switch months by "<>" buttons (regardless which calendar view - day, week, month - in use) - script upload new month records by ajax/json and place them in calendar. Don't know how to do that, but i am going to read over the documentation  carefully.

If you have experience how overcome this problem of fetching to many records in Calendar events - please share.

Thanks

Comment: Hi Guys, probably I've found what to do. Why I am passing an array of records from Controller to View, if I can parse all records to JSON string and pass to View only one variable. And no limits hit. It is not an answer for my question, but a solution for the problem.

Answer (score 2):

fullCalendar already has this feature, check this out, https://fullcalendar.io/docs/events-json-feed

Answer (score 0):

you are looking for gotoDate (http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/current_date/gotoDate/) which will refetch your events for the given date object or year and month.

From documentation:

```
.fullCalendar( 'gotoDate', year [, month, [ date ]] )
```

Comment: Great, just great. There is nothing about event refetching in description of this method, so thanks a lot for your information. Thus can I fire this code by clicking in Calendar buttons '<>'? Is there any special click event for those buttons? Or can we hang a handler on those buttons? Or it is easier to create your our buttons with month-event switch logic? Calendar PlugIn is very interesting project.

Comment: Sorry I was thinking of using different navigation buttons. Sulaiman is correct you should use http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_data/events_json_feed/.